# Execute counter script when element is scrolled to on webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I'm completely new to javascript. I'm trying to execute a counting script but I only want it to start when you scroll to the element on-screen (so you can see the counting). Currently, my code currently only works on page load. Can somebody please help me? Thanks.

Here is the html code element:`<span class="count">100</span>`

here is the script that currently works on page load:

```
$('.count').each(function () {
$(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
}, {
    duration: 4000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function (now) {
        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
$element = $('.count');
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var hT = $element.offset().top,
       hH = $element.outerHeight(),
       wH = $(window).height(),
       wS = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
       $element.each(function () {
       $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
           Counter: $(this).text()
           }, {
               duration: 4000,
               easing: 'swing',
               step: function (now) {
                   $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
               }
           });
       });
   }
});
```

What it does is validate the current scroll offset against the element offset in the page. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, while this code did start the counting when I scrolled to it. It is also acting very funky as in it counts up, then counts right back down to 0, then starts very slowly counting up again. I'm looking for it to count up only once and stay at that number unless they reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found a solution someone else had done. I'm sure there is a simpler script possible but this one works like a charm. I edited the SPAN element like so:
`<span class="timer count-title count-number" data-to="100" data-speed="5000"></span>`

I then used the **updated Feb 2** javascript code found @ [Bootstrap counter start on display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006848/bootstrap-counter-start-on-display). Hope this helps others looking for a scroll-to activated counter.